# Eclipse BPEL web service deployment testing

Tags: eclipse, wsdl, bpel

I have created a BPEL project in eclipse using BPEL visual designer. After deployment, i can right click on .wsdl file and choose Web services >> Test with web services explorer. 
This opens up a window in eclipse itself.
Is there a way to do this in browser (chrome etc..) ?
Also, i know this is pretty basic, but how to use the generated wsdl and Bpel(like how to deploy in server(in my localhost) for instance ). Any links on basics would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a good web-based Web service testing tool. You may give the try-it functionality of WSO2's products a try. In any case, I recommend using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org), which is absolutely awesome for testing Web services.